# Companion instantly turns hostile once talked to: How do you change your companion's relationship rating?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

After visiting Eldergleam Sanctuary to retrieve a sapling from a big tree for a quest, whenever I "talk" to my companion by pressing "E", she (Uthgerd the Unbroken) instantly turns hostile and starts attacking me...

Strangely, If I crouched into sneak mode, then talk to her, she does not turn hostile. This extra step wasn't a big deal for me.

However, now that I need to fast travel to other cities, console says, "Unable to fast travel due to enemies nearby". My guess is that my companion is the nature of this error...

So, how do you fix your companion's relationship rating, console or non-console-wise? I've already tried `setrelationshiprating` using console, but it failed to fix things. I tried killing her and resurrect her, and she came back hostile.

Answer (score 8):

I managed to solve this problem by:

1. crouch and tell her to leave
2. run asap to somewhere far
3. fast travel to where the companion would return and ask him/her to follow you again

All the items I stuffed her with seems intact :D:D

Comment: It sounds wrong to have items stuffed in her. Oh well life goes on.

Comment: @SomeNoobStudent - If this solved your problem, do you want to mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 6):

Use the console command:

```
 player.setrelationshiprank <actor> 4
```

where `<actor>` is the character's player ID. For example, for Lydia her player ID is a2c94.
You can find the Player ID by searching Google for their name, or by looking in the Skyrim Wiki.

p.s. this only works on PC

p.s.s. on PC, get to the Console by typing the "tilde" key on your keyboard, which is ~ or ` and is the key that is usually right under the Esc key and to the left of the 1 key.

**UPDATE:**

If this doesn't work, then try this:

Click on player, then type into console:

```
setav aggression 0
```

Also you may try: 
Click on player, then type into console:

```
forceav aggression 0
```

**They are attacking you because their aggression is very high.** Aggression is between -3 and +3. -3 means extremely passive, +3 means attack everything. It sounds like she is +1 or +2. If 0 doesn't work (it should), you could try setting or forcing at -3, like this:

```
setav aggression -3
```

Answer (score 2):

Run away from her until you can fast travel or wait. After a day (or more) the relationship should go back to normal.

Comment: That's because she will "cool down" and not be so angry. Fixing it in console is easier and faster.

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact same problem, i avoided talking to her until i ran into some guards who arrested me (my guess is i accumulated too many stolen items).

I payed the fine, was taken back to the city, and everything with Uthgerd is fine.

Answer (score -1):

Just beat your companion up and then talk to them.
should fix the problem.

Comment: I'm sure that hitting someone wouldn't stop hositility.